# Check for key in NSDictionary - not working with boolean NSNumber as value @iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just found a strange issue with NSDictionary on an iOS 8 (@ 8.1.1 & 8.1.2). Didn't encounter this issue with all other devices I could test with (including (8.1) simulator).
With iOS8 checking for a key in a NSDictionary object does not work as expected under the following conditions:

1. the value to the key is a NSNumber object initialized with boolean value YES
2. dict[@"testKey"] or [dict objectForKey:@"testKey"] is used to check if key exists
3. the checking result is stored into a BOOL variable

First see the following example code (I'm aware that you can compress the whole checking mechanism in one line - it is just to illustrate the issue):

```
-(void) doSomethingDependingOn:(BOOL)foo andBar:(BOOL)bar andAttr:(NSDictionary*)dict {
BOOL doAction = NO;

    if (foo) {
        doAction = dict[@"trigger1"];   // check if key exists in dictionary
    }

    if (bar) {
        doAction = dict[@"trigger2"];   // check if key exists in dictionary
    }

    if (doAction) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This code is working fine - except for the case that it is running on a real iOS 8 device (not simulator) and the value at the checked keys is a NSNumber object initialized with boolean value YES. In this case the key-exists-check FAILS - meaning that variable doAction is set to NO eventhough the key exists and you find a perfectly fine object for this key (NSNumber with boolean value YES or integer 1). 
To me it seems like this is an iOS 8 bug.

You can verify this with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key1" : [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"key2" : @"value2"};
BOOL opt_1 = [dict objectForKey:@"key1"];
BOOL opt_2 = dict[@"key1"];
BOOL opt_3 = ([dict objectForKey:@"key1"] ? 1 : 0);

if ([dict objectForKey:@"key1"]) NSLog(@"1. OK");
if (dict[@"key1"]) NSLog(@"2. OK");

if (opt_1) NSLog(@"opt_1 OK");
if (opt_2) NSLog(@"opt_2 OK");
if (opt_3) NSLog(@"opt_3 OK");

NSLog(@"check ref: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] -> %p\tdict[@\"key1\"] -> %p",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],dict[@"key1"]);
```

Output @ iOS8:

```
- 1. OK
- 2. OK
- opt_3 OK
- check ref: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] -> 0x3303b900    dict[@"key1"] -> 0x3303b900
```

Output @ other devices:

```
- 1. OK
- 2. OK
- opt_1 OK
- opt_2 OK
- opt_3 OK
- check ref: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] -> 0x3eb319f0    dict[@"key1"] -> 0x3eb319f0
```

I have no explanation for this. Is it a bug?

EDIT: added print out for pointer ref to value (value check)

SOLVED: Thanks to CRD! It was a bug in my code not in iOS 8 - surprise. ;-) `BOOL keyCheck = [dict objectForKey:@"key1"];` is an invalid way to check whether key is available in dictionary or not. That's it! You live and you learn & you code and you learn. Thanks everybody for your input!

Comment: `BOOL opt_3 = ([dict objectForKey:@"key1"] ? 1 : 0);` Since you can't place a `nil` value in a dictionary, this test will always be true, if the value is present at all.

Comment: The assignments to `BOOL opt_1` and `BOOL opt_2` are bogus, since you're assigning a pointer to a BOOL.

Comment: You should definitely be using `[... boolValue]` here...

Comment: Thank you for your replies! However, to me this makes no sense. Also consider that this code is working all the time except for this specific case with iOS 8. In my opinion, if you can write "if (dict[@"key1"])", you should also be able to write "BOOL result = if (dict[@"key1"])" - it's the same examination (using a pointer, I'm aware). @Ian MacDonald: I don't know but calling [... boolValue] - if the object doesn't exist is also not so nice. Hot Licks: Yes, I'm aware. Just wanted to give an working example. Best solution would be "BOOL opt_3 = ([dict objectForKey:@"key1"]!=nil)" I guess.

Comment: If the object does not exist, the `BOOL` result will be `NO` (the result of evaluating `nil` as a `BOOL`). You can change this default by checking for its existence first and then only checking `boolValue` when it exists. In all other cases, the result will correctly be the value contained within the `NSNumber` primitive wrapper. Without accessing `boolValue`, you are addressing the object and not the primitive value.

Comment: What makes no sense is your code.  And when code makes no sense then essentially any behavior coming out of it is "valid".  And that (valid in the face of nonsense) behavior is quite likely to vary with compiler version, OS release, and (especially) default word size.

Comment: I added example code to make it more clear. There was a misunderstanding: I don't want to assign a boolean variable to a pointer - I'm just checking whether the key exists or not. It's a coincident that the key check fails if the object for the key is a NSNumber object initialized with boolean value YES.

Comment: Out of curiosity can you `NSLog` the value of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` and `dict[@"key1"]` using `%p`, i.e. display the value of the reference, under both scenarios?

Comment: @CRD: I added the print out for the reference. Looks ok so far I think.

Comment: @LordBullington - Bingo, answer coming in a moment...

Comment: @CRD: I'm excited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there is an error in the code, its not a bug (though some might argue its a *language* bug, but that's another issue ;-))

In C a conditional statement takes an expression which is tested for being "unequal to 0", and there are various types - the numeric types (which includes `char` and `BOOL`) and the pointer types - which can be compared to 0. For pointers 0 represents the *null pointer constant*, usually represented in Obj-C as `nil`. So your statement:

```
BOOL opt_3 = ([dict objectForKey:@"key1"] ? 1 : 0);
```

is directly equivalent by the language specification to:

```
BOOL opt_3 = ([dict objectForKey:@"key1"] != nil ? 1 : 0);
```

Also in C pointers can be converted to integers and different sizes of integer type can be converted to each other. If the conversion is to a larger type the conversion is *implicit*,  otherwise it is *explicit* - however compilers may just warn in the latter case and compile the code as though the conversion was explicit. This is what Xcode does with your two statements:

```
BOOL opt_1 = [dict objectForKey:@"key1"];
BOOL opt_2 = dict[@"key1"];
```

which produce a warning, the `BOOL` type is smaller than an object reference, but compiles. You can put in an explicit `(BOOL)` cast to silence the warning, but that won't fix the bug.

The problem comes from how C does a conversion from the larger type to the smaller one - it just *truncates* - regardless of the mathematical/logical correctness of the result. So what the above two statements do is assign the least significant byte of the pointer value to the `BOOL` variables (as `BOOL` is one byte).

Now look at the pointer values you've added to the question. On non-iOS8 devices the value is `0x3eb319f0`, which truncated to a byte is `0xf0`, and that interpreted as a `BOOL` is true (anything non-zero is true).

On iOS8 the value is `0x3303b900`, which truncated to a byte is `0x00`, which is `BOOL` `NO`.

These values are of course "random" - you could have got the opposite result with iOS8 apparently working, or some mixture. Indeed the same test in different parts of the program *may* produce different results. This also explains why an `NSNumber` representing `1` may give a different result to one representing `YES`.

To fix your code simply change it to:

```
BOOL opt_1 = [dict objectForKey:@"key1"] != nil;
BOOL opt_2 = dict[@"key1"] != nil;
```

and it should work.

HTH

Comment: Thank you a lot! So conditional statements are treated differently than the assignment of the same statement to a boolean variable which I did. So it was just "good luck" that this code was working for several years - until the least significant byte was 0x00. Which coincidentally now happened with iOS 8 devices. So all is fine. Already fixed it in my project. Unfortunately I can't vote you up :( Thank you anyways!

Comment: Well after failing to see the conversions for the comparisons we got there in the end. Glad it helped. The next surprise awaiting you is that C operators like `!=` actually return an integer and not a boolean so statements like `a += b > c` are correct...